# how to use envelop distort perfectly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want the word 'homestead' in the center of that shape in a nice curvy fashion.

I have applied 'ENVELOP DISTORT' 'MAKE WITH TOP OBJECT' option.
Have applied several slanted form but none produce the result i am expecting.

Please help me.
[image]

Comment: --- "*produce the result i am expecting.*" -- How are we to know what you are expecting?

Comment: I want the word 'homestead' in the center of that shape in a nice curvy fashion.-- SAW THT LINE?? it answers your question.

Comment: Believe it or not "Make with top object" depends **a lot** on that top object and *where* it's anchor points are located. It looks like you may have anchor points in the middle of the side curves.

Comment: i made tht happen. i found it out. but a slight change i had to make. in this picture i cut tht left and right with circle.it didnt work. but then i use rectangle and cut left right in a straight fashion. then it works.  :)    BUT i really wanted to fit 'HOMESTEAD'  in the shape i drew... :'(

Comment: You can still make it fit you just make the mesh that shape. Anyway its a bit unneseserily complex to do the distortion on the bezier equation. At minimum adobe should allow for length parametrisation... Since that is what humans expect.

Answer (score 3):

Use an Envelope distort with a mesh instead. Do *Object > Envelope distort > Make with mesh*. A single column and single row mesh should be enough, then move the Bézier handles to make some curves.

Example:

[image]

Comment: .... may be this is how it needs to be done at last... but i needed 'homestead' in that particular shape....  anyway. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping texts and images on a 3D surface is possible in Illustrator. The rendered 2D image can be the wanted one. The same result made with envelope distortion can be much more time consuming job due the complexity of the needed mesh. An example:

[image]

- the text + frame as dragged to the symbols collection
- a simple shape to be revolved, now a circle
- the revolution surface "torus" with default rendering (=plastic shading)
- the revolution dialog  reopened from the appearance panel, the plastic shading is removed, the view is rotated to more tilted,art is mapped

[image]

- expand appearance (=fix the effect) is applied
- the clipping mask is released
- everything is ungrouped 3 times, all but the text is deleted
- a new frame is drawn manually because expanding the original had caused non-uniform edge thickness.

The method has drawbacks:

- the possibilities are limited because there's only extrusion and revolution available to create the 3D geometry.
- special care is needed to get a surface which the art is easy to map on. Illustrator often splits too complex surfaces in a bizarre way to pieces which are nearly impossible to be covered with art, but simple enough surfaces can be a success.
- to separate the wanted part one must expand the appearance, remove clipping mask, make numerous ungroupings, delete an incredible amount of stray scuff and combine the wanted parts with the Shape Builder from numerous splinters

The next image is an attempt to make something I guess actually was expected. It's substantially more complex than the torus example:

[image]

1. The text and the revolved shape. Revolved and extruded shapes should have no stroke if one expects a possibility to separate parts afterwards. Strokes make the result hopelessly complex.

2.-3. the revolved shape and mapping the art. There's no perspective (=forgotten) but it was fixed partially at the end with bulging. Note the thin black stroke on the text. Such stray artefacts occur in Illustrator's 3D

4. The appearance is expanded, clipping mesks are released, groups are ungrouped, all grey is deleted. There's still much extra parts, the frame and the text are made of splinters
5. the wanted parts are combined with the Shape Builder, a bunch of unwanted shapes and anchor points are deleted
6. Envelope distortion Warp > Bulge is added to fix partially the forgotten perspective.

Comment: oh man! it seems like am looking at 3ds max! i did same thing on sketch up. when i want to put texture on a curvy/wavy object i use kind of  similar approach  you described. illustrator is not at dealing curvy thing- tht is what i learnt yesterday.  Thank you for making such effort! am gonna learn it.